# Delete selection without gradient effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, selections

I am trying to delete a selection but I get this gradient effect when I hit delete.

This is the selection I want to delete:

[image]

After I hit delete I get this:

[image]

How to delete the selection without getting that gradient effect?

I am using the rectangle marquee tool. I also apply a feather of 25 pixels to get rounded corners then I select inverse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its the actual feather producing that edge blur.

If you need a rounded rectangle, use the Rounded Rectangle Tool, with settings for corner radius, fill, etc: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/edit-rounded-rectangles.html